# Matplotlib animation not adding the counter from inside the animate function

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

I don't understand why the counter inside de animate function is not getting added to itself.

I tried to use the animation to print new values of two lists of values, each one each axis, each second.

**EDITED:** The code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = [1, 12, 10, 1, 5, 3, 5, 7, 4, 4]

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

cnt = 0
def animate(i, cnt):
    print(cnt)
    print('loop ' + str(cnt))

    x_vals.append(x[cnt])
    y_vals.append(y[cnt])

    print(x_vals, y_vals)
    cnt += 1  # this is not happening
    plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals, label='Price')

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, fargs=(cnt,), interval=1000)

# plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I declare cnt outside the animate function and I get this output ( thank's [PartialOrder](http://PartialOrder) user):

```
0
loop 0
[1] [1]
0
loop 0
[1, 1] [1, 1]
0
loop 0
[1, 1, 1] [1, 1, 1]
....
```

Which shows that the loop in the animate function is executed each second, but counter not getting added because reset to zero each loop.
And if declare cnt counter before the function (not passed in argument), I get:

```
File "test3.py", line 13, in animate
    print('loop ' + str(cnt))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cnt' referenced before assignment
```

Both ways I get an empty graph:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEi46.png)

Why the counter is not getting added, and how to pass external counter to the function?

Thank you!

Comment: You're re-initializing `cnt` on each call to `animate`

Comment: Yes, but if I declare before assignment get an error.. I'll edit to post with all the other code used

Comment: You can pass additional params to FuncAnimation using fargs. E.g., `ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, fargs=(cnt,), interval=1000)`. See: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html

Comment: Read on "global variables in python".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah!!!!... global worked!!! Thank you!!! @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = [1, 12, 10, 1, 5, 3, 5, 7, 4, 4]

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

cnt = 0
def animate(i):
    global cnt
    if cnt == 10:
        exit('Finished')
    print('loop ' + str(cnt))

    x_vals.append(x[cnt])
    y_vals.append(y[cnt])

    print(x_vals, y_vals)
    cnt += 1  # this is not happening
    plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals, label='Price')

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=1000)

plt.show()
```